# Check if zip is password encrypted (using JS)

Tags: javascript, passwords, zip

Is it possible to somehow check if zip file is password encrypted without uploading it to a server?

Comment: https://github.com/augustl/js-unzip/tree/8b8260da4d6b2189e02e1ca76592c729e1a7b307

Comment: thanks, I'll try it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if zip or gzip is password encrypted (Node.JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677993/check-if-zip-or-gzip-is-password-encrypted-node-js)