# Check if zip or gzip is password encrypted (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, encryption, zip, gzip

I've had a bad time trying to see if a zip or gzip has password protected files. I'm used to DotNetZip to seeing in .net but in Node.js I can't seem to find an equivalent.

I'm able to see if the file is a gzip or a zip by checking the lead bytes but not if they contain encrypted files, this may be by gpg, traditional or even aes.

I've tried using the packages `unzip`, `unzip2` and `adm-unzip` but they just haven't solved my issues.

**I'm looking for a pure node.js implementation.**

At this point, I'm just considering writing my own module to solve my issue.

Comment: https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#isencrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl#isencrypted at this current moment in time but if anyone else can find something that can also do pdf's and .docx files, that'd be great!